# How to import a CSV file with a column with YYYYMMDD to a DATE column in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I´d like to import a `CSV` file with a column with `YYYYMMDD` to a `DATE` column in `ClickHouse`. Sample of `CSV` `content: 20191231`. I realized that `ClickHouse` only import a `DATE` column in `CSV` if it in the format as is `YYYY-MM-DD` (only with "`-`" between the year, month and day). I can not change the format in the `CSV` file that is stored in a `http server`.
Please let me know an easy way or command to import hundred `CSV` files with `YYYYMMDD` from a `http server` or where can I change the configuration in my `clickhouse` server to accept `YYYYMMDD` format instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`?

I already added a new column, imported all files and updated the table. See the query below. The field '`olddatefield`' is a `STRING` and '`newdatefield`' is a DATE field.

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN newdatefield Date AFTER olddatefield;

ALTER TABLE test
UPDATE newdatefield = toDate(concat(substring(olddatefield, 1, 4), '-' , substring(olddatefield, 5, 2), '-' , substring(olddatefield, 7, 2)))
WHERE olddatefield = '20191231';
```

It worked very well, but there are thousands files with different `DATES` to import and I dont want edit thousands of `'alter table'` queries.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to rely on [parseDateTimeBestEffort](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql_reference/functions/type_conversion_functions/#parsedatetimebesteffort) function:

```sql
SELECT toDate(parseDateTimeBestEffort('20191231')) AS date
/*
┌───────date─┐
│ 2019-12-31 │
└────────────┘
*/
```

And then using [input](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql_reference/table_functions/input/)-table function need to change a data upload way to fix related field(s):

```sh
cat data.csv \
  | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO test SELECT toDate(parseDateTimeBestEffort(date)) AS date, id FROM input('date String, id Int32') FORMAT CSV";
```

*data.csv*

```
20191231, 1
20200101, 2
```